# Flask. Could not build url for endpoint 'index'

Tags: python, flask

Please help in solving this problem.
I have a project in Flask with a structure:

```
project
- main.py
- app
-- __init__.py
-- main
--- __init__.py
--- routes.py
-- auth
--- __init__.py
--- routes.py
--- forms.py
-- templates
--- index.html
```

app/main/routes.py

```
from flask import render_template
from app.main import bp


@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

app/main/**init**.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

from app.main import routes
```

app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

def create_app(config_class=Config):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    from app.auth import bp as auth_bp
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp, url_prefix='/auth')

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    return app
```

main.py

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I get an error when I start the application:

```
Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you mean 'main.index' instead?
```

Tried to insert main.index. instead of index.html in combination with template_folder='../templates'. But then it doesn't find the template.

Comment: Could you share the full error traceback?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a mystery. Another time, after turning on the laptop, it worked.